# How to store location of selected video from PhotoLibrary

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

When selecting a video from the Photo Library, iOS compresses the video and stores it in the tmp/ folder.  That location is returned as the '.mediaURL' and is used to load the video into an AVPlayer.  I am trying to save the location of the selected video so it can be played back later, but I found that the tmp/ url is cleared out at some point after closing the app and reopening it.  For music, I can store the 'persistentID' to retrieve the songs later. I have not been able to find a good way to persist the location of the originally selected video so it can be replayed later without having to select it again during the current session.  Looking for suggestions.

I am using Swift 5 for iOS.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use imagePicker to select a video from gallery , you need to copy it someWhere say inside the documents folder to be able to persistently reference it when you open the app again

Comment: I was hoping not to have to create a persistent copy of the video file.  I started looking at that option but was hoping for something like the persistentId for music.
Thanks, I'll experiment with that option.

Comment: this is the way to go with similar cases the url given by the picker is temporary that you shouldn't depend on it

Comment: Yeah, for images I'm just storing it as data since they aren't that big and I only use one image at a time.  I was just thinking the video file would be much larger, but again as it will only be one video stored at a time that may not be bad.

Comment: This approach worked.  However, I found that when installing and running on my iPhone from the Xcode ide, the document location changed each time, so saving the previous document location still caused a problem.  I found a solution on another thread by searching for the current document location to retrieve the saved video file. Oddly, even tho the document path value would change, the file was still located after each launch.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I found:

To save the selected video:

```
func saveVideoToDirectory(videoUrl: NSURL) {
    let videoData = NSData(contentsOf: videoUrl as URL)
    let path = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
    let newPath = path.appendingPathComponent("/backgroundVideo.mp4")
    do {
        try videoData?.write(to: newPath)
        let movieData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: newPath)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(movieData, forKey: "movie")
        //print("movie url: ", newPath)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

to retrieve the video:

```
let movieData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "movie") as? Data
let movieUrl = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as! URL
//search for current documents path       
let docPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]

let videoUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: docPath.appendingFormat("/backgroundVideo.mp4"))

let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: videoUrl as URL)
```